# mapping control followed by two characters in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I like switching my focus back and forth between the NERDTREE pane and a file and the command `Ctrl-ww` accomplishes this.  I'd like to map this to `<Leader>w` but variations of `map <Leader>w <C-ww><CR>` in my `.vimrc` are not working for me.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this mapping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not `<C-ww>`, it's `<C-w>w` or `<C-w><C-w>`.

That's either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

So your mapping should be `nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w>w` or `nnoremap <Leader>w <C-w><C-w>`.

Note that you can use `<C-w>p` to move to the previous window and effectively toggle between NERDTree and your active window.

See `:help window` for more infos on windows in Vim.